# How to implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a wizard generated app with navigation drawer in android studio 0.8.2

I have created a fragment and added it with newInstance() and I get this error:

> com.domain.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: com.domain.myapp.MainActivity@422fb8f0  must implement
>   OnFragmentInteractionListener

I can't find anywhere how to implement this OnFragmentInteractionListener ??
It cannot be found even in android sdk documentation!

MainActivity.java

```java
import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    switch (position) {
        case 0: fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit(); break; 
        case 1: fragmentManager.beginTransaction() 
                .replace(R.id.container, AboutFragment.newInstance("test1", "test2"))
                .commit(); break; // this crashes the app
        case 2: fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, BrowseQuotesFragment.newInstance("test1", "test2"))
                .commit(); break; // this crashes the app
    }
}


public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Answers posted here did not help, but the following link did:

**http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html**

### Define an Interface

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

For example, the following method in the fragment is called when the user clicks on a list item. The fragment uses the callback interface to deliver the event to the parent activity.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Send the event to the host activity
    mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);
}
```

### Implement the Interface

For example, the following activity implements the interface from the above example.

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
    ...

    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
        // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
        // Do something here to display that article
    }
}
```

---

**Update for API 23: 8/31/2015**

Overrided method `onAttach(Activity activity)` is now deprecated in `android.app.Fragment`, code should be upgraded to `onAttach(Context context)`

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

Comment: please note that `onAttach(Activity activity);` is deprecated, and replaced with `onAttach(Context context)`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Indeed  you are right, I updated my post to reflect that

Comment: Is there any reason why it moves from onAttach to onStart? can I still put it in onAttach just using context instead of activity?

Comment: I think just using `onAttach(context)` would work fine

Answer (score 214):

For those of you who still don't understand after reading @meda answer, here is my concise and complete explanation for this issue:

Let's say you have 2 Fragments, `Fragment_A` and `Fragment_B` which are auto-generated from the app. On the bottom part of your generated fragments, you're going to find this code:

```
public class Fragment_A extends Fragment {

    //rest of the code is omitted

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}

public class Fragment_B extends Fragment {

    //rest of the code is omitted

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

To overcome the issue, you have to add `onFragmentInteraction` method into your activity, which in my case is named `MainActivity2`. After that, you need to `implements` all fragments in the `MainActivity` like this:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity
        implements Fragment_A.OnFragmentInteractionListener, 
                   Fragment_B.OnFragmentInteractionListener, 
                   NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    //rest code is omitted

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
        //you can leave it empty
    }
}
```

P.S.: In short, this method could be used for communicating between fragments. For those of you who want to know more about this method, please refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Comment: With current version of the SDK in Android Studio, it *requires* you to implement the `onFragmentIntereactior(Uri)` method, which is not mentioned in any of the other answers. +1

Comment: Glad that it can help a lot of people.. :)

Comment: Requires? You can just erase the code related to the listeners... If you happen to have fragments that don't need to interact with other fragments, those listeners are useless.

Comment: I am getting error "can not resolve NavigationDrawerFragment"

Comment: Much easier to follow and understand than the accepted answer.

Comment: @html_programmer Thanks that helped me. The Fragment I'm currently working on doesn't need any interaction with the MainActivity, at least at this point.

Answer (score 44):

See your auto-generated `Fragment` created by Android Studio.  When you created the new `Fragment`, Studio stubbed a bunch of code for you.  At the bottom of the auto-generated template there is an inner interface definition called `OnFragmentInteractionListener`.  Your `Activity` needs to implement this interface.  This is the recommended pattern for your `Fragment` to notify your `Activity` of events so it can then take appropriate action, such as load another `Fragment`.  See this page for details, look for the "Creating event callbacks for the Activity" section: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: In the documentation shows how to implement the listener in the fragment (which is already generated by wizard), but not in the mainactivity which causes the app to crash.

Comment: Not exactly.  The doc (and the generated code) define the interface and check against it when the `Activity` is attached to the `Fragment`.  The crash you are seeing is because your `Activity` has not implemented the interface.  You need to go into your `Activity` and add a `implements YourFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener` then add an implementation of the method defined in the interface.

Comment: ok, but I don't know how to add that implementation because it's nowhere in the android sdk documentation

Comment: It's not part of the SDK, but a best practice.  The template code produced by the wizard is just laying the groundwork for you.  The interface's `onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri)` is just a stub.  You can make this method anything you want and your `Activity` needs to implement it.  See if [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) helps.

Comment: This hint saved many hours. While creating fragment UN-check "include fragment factory methods" and "include interface callbacks". And you don't have to implement OnFragmentInteractionListener. I'm using Android studio 1.3.2 with Java sdk 8. Android 6.0 (API 23) and sdk-platform 23 is. Thank you Larry Schiefer.

Answer (score 27):

For those of you who visit this page looking for further clarification on this error, in my case the activity making the call to the fragment needed to have 2 implements in this case, like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements 
    MyFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, 
    NavigationDrawerFragment.NaviationDrawerCallbacks {
    ...// rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You should try removing the following code from your fragments

```
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
```

The interface/listener is a default created so that your activity and fragments can communicate easier

Comment: This is a very good point since this listener is not needed in most beginner apps.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @user26409021 's answer, If you have added a ItemFragment, The message in the ItemFragment is;

```
Activities containing this fragment MUST implement the {@link OnListFragmentInteractionListener} interface.
```

And You should add in your activity;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, ItemFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener {

//the code is omitted

 public void onListFragmentInteraction(DummyContent.DummyItem uri){
    //you can leave it empty
}
```

Here the dummy item is what you have on the bottom of your ItemFragment

Answer (score 5):

With me it worked delete this code:

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }
```

Ending like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`OnFragmentInteractionListener` is the default implementation for handling fragment to activity communication. This can be implemented based on your needs. Suppose if you need a function in your activity to be executed during a particular action within your fragment, you may make use of this callback method. If you don't need to have this interaction between your hosting `activity` and `fragment`, you may remove this implementation.

In short you should `implement` the listener in your fragment hosting activity if you need the fragment-activity interaction like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
YourFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {..}
```

and your fragment should have it defined like this

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

also provide definition for `void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);` in your activity

or else just remove the `listener` initialisation from your fragment's `onAttach` if you dont have any fragment-activity interaction

Answer (score 3):

**Instead of Activity use context.It works for me.**

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just an addendum:

**OnFragmentInteractionListener handle communication between Activity and Fragment using an interface** (OnFragmentInteractionListener) and **is created by default by Android Studio, but if you dont need to communicate with your activity, you can just get ride of  it.**

**The goal is that you can attach your fragment to multiple activities and still reuse the same communication approach** (Every activity could have its own OnFragmentInteractionListener for each fragment).

**But and if im sure my fragment will be attached to only one type of activity and i want to communicate with that activity?**

Then, if you dont want to use OnFragmentInteractionListener because of its verbosity, you can access your activity methods using:

```
((MyActivityClass) getActivity()).someMethod()
```

Comment: Although this would work in most cases, sometimes getActivity() can return null if the fragments has detached from the activity while this is being called, for example in the postExecute method of an asynctask, if you call get activity but have already left the fragment before the asyncTask has completed then you would get a null pointer exception. For this reason the android documents specifically say to use a fragment interaction listener interface

Answer (score 2):

Just go to your fragment Activity and remove all method.....instead on on createview method.

your fragment has only on method oncreateview that's it.

//only this method implement other method delete

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

and make sure your layout it is demo for u.

Comment: Thank You... If needs Something kalpeshnikam1080@gmail.com drop mail

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add the destruction of the listener when the fragment is detached from the activity or destroyed.

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
```

and when using the new onStart() method with Context

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mListener = null;
}
```