# Implementing OnFragmentInteractionListener in Tabbed Activity w/ ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

Using Android Studio's Tabbed Activity with the navigation style: Tabbed Activity (ViewPager) to create swipeable navigation tabs. Was beginning to start figuring out how to edit fragments for each tab, so I added...

```
        @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return new YourFragmentClass1();
            case 1:
                return new YourFragmentClass2();
            case 2:
                return new YourFragmentClass3();
            case 3:
                return new YourFragmentClass4();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

...and created 4 fragment classes. When I went to run it I got a force close and told that that I needed to implement OnFragmentInteractionListener at roughly 39 places. I haven't been able to find any content that solves the issue, and am a bit overwhelmed on where to start. Is there something within my main activity that needs to be resolved first, or does it lie within each of the fragment activities?

**Here's my main activity code and my LogCat:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return new YourFragmentClass1();
            case 1:
                return new YourFragmentClass2();
            case 2:
                return new YourFragmentClass3();
            case 3:
                return new YourFragmentClass4();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}



java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nicholasthompson.tabtest.MyActivity@420264e8 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
        at com.nicholasthompson.tabtest.YourFragmentClass1.onAttach(YourFragmentClass1.java:84)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:849)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:785)
        at android.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:997)
        at android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompatICSMR1.setUserVisibleHint(FragmentCompatICSMR1.java:23)
        at android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat$ICSMR1FragmentCompatImpl.setUserVisibleHint(FragmentCompat.java:48)
        at android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat.setUserVisibleHint(FragmentCompat.java:76)
        at android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:134)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1066)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16617)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5145)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16617)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5145)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16617)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5145)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16617)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1188)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1397)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1075)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5878)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Look into this question as it seems like it will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777985/how-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener

Comment: Thanks, this was one of the first bits I read trying to figure out my issue.

Comment: Looks like you need your `MyActivity` to implement tablistener and the onfragmentinteractionlistener but it currently only implemenets the tablistener

Comment: I'm guessing it's something similar to this: extends Activity implements MyFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, NavigationDrawerFragment.NaviationDrawerCallbacks
As referenced in the link you provided. But adding, MyFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener it didn't like.

Comment: It may have to be PlaceholderFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, I think they used MyFragment as an example

Comment: Ah, haha, I was just wondering about that. Let me see if that will work.

Comment: public class MyActivity extends Activity implements PlaceholderFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, ActionBar.TabListener, 

Is what I currently have, and now it says that 'OnFragmentInteractionListener' cannot be resolved

Comment: It looks like it is actually for the fragments that you are using in your getItem, ie. YourFragmentClass1

Comment: So do I need a "super" fragment class that it can call too, calling to just one of the fragments seems like it wouldn't get me what I need.

Comment: It appears to be the case, or, if you do not actually need the functionality that the onFragmentInteractionListener will give you, you can remove the interface from the fragments and the calls to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement onFragmentInteractionListener in each activity that hosts the fragments. Each fragment, when created by the wizard, has an interface at the bottom that must be used. In that interface you can define whatever methods you find relevant to your fragment.

See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Implement

I prefer to define one interface, and have all the fragments, or a group of fragments use that Interface. Otherwise you might end up with an activity, that is forced to implement X number of interfaces, where X is the number of Fragments you have created.