# How do I Add A Fragment to a Custom Navigation Drawer Template?

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design

I am using a custom material design navigation drawer template from https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template in android studio.
I am able to run the navigation drawer, but when i am trying to add a fragment to the drawer,the whole code stops and gives error. The way i tried to add fragment is.

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) 
{ 
    // update the main content by replacing fragments 
    Fragment fragment; 
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); // For AppCompat use getSupportFragmentManager 
    switch(position) 
    {
        default: case 0: 
            fragment = new Fragment1(); 
            break; 
        case 1: fragment = new Fragment2(); 
            break; 
    } 
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit(); 
    Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item selected -> " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```

My Error In Logcat is

```
08-17 00:29:59.548    4470-4470/com.example.geevarughese.nav2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.geevarughese.nav2, PID: 4470
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.geevarughese.nav2/com.example.geevarughese.nav2.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.geevarughese.nav2.MainActivity@3ddc1486 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.geevarughese.nav2.MainActivity@3ddc1486 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
            at com.example.geevarughese.nav2.Fragment1.onAttach(Fragment1.java:83)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:907)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.geevarughese.nav2.MainActivity@3ddc1486 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

It looks like `ClassCastException` is caused due to absence of `OnFragmentInteractionListener` which you need to implement. I do not want to duplicate the effort so here is where you can find the solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777985/how-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener

Just let me know if you need any help. Cheers!

Comment: Yes .ofcourse. first Let me try to solve this. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forgot to implement the `OnFragmentInteractionListener` interface on your `MainActivity`. When you implement that your `ClassCastException` should be gone.

Comment: Can u please show me an example. because in this template OnFragmentInteractionListener is used as an interface for callbacks. so when i make any changes in the code,the whole activity gets error.