# Is this the right way to call Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, listener

I have this Android project, where from the `MainActivity` I call some `Fragments`.

But without including `FragmentName.OnFragmentInteractionListeners` in the `MainActivity` I am not able to go to those `Fragments`.

```
Public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements DirectoryFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    HireDriverFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
```

What I am worrying about is that I should do this for each `Fragment`.

If I don't add those `Listeners` I will get these errors when I try to initiate those `Fragments`.

```
must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

If need more code to provide a better solution I am ready to provide.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26473328/4385913)

Comment: Ok, so seems that I have to implement every single fragment?

Comment: Wait, let me test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I am worried is that should I do this for every single fragment?

You could create an `Interface` as [Communicating Android Document](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) says, and then you'll have to add the `onFragmentInteractionListener` on your `Fragments`.

Also take a look on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777985/how-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener) there are many answers that might help you :)

Comment: all the suggestions seems to point that I have to implement each and every fragment

Comment: Would sharing my code help in getting the actual answer?

Comment: What do you mean? It doesn't help to you?

Comment: @JackyBoi Shall I update my answer? didn't work for you?