# Android: How to interact with other fragment in the same activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can't figure out how to interact with other fragments. I know I need to implement the OnFragmentInteractionListener but I don't know what is the properly ways to pass to the listener.

The OnFragmentInteractionListener has method which take Uri as a parameter. What is the structure of the that Uri we have to pass in.

Why not object instead of Uri.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement OnFragmentInteractionListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777985/how-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener)

Comment: OnFragmentInteractionListener is nothing which is provided by android you can create your own interface with parameter in callback method which you required for pass the data.

Comment: 1) Uri class is an object 2) Uri does what? You can easily change that to whatever you actually need