# My App crashes with the error: must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I watched a tutorial about first steps with the android studio. In this tutorial a guy is teaching how to make an android navigation drawer including the widget actions. I did all he did but I'm getting an error called `must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener`. I've searched on stackoverflow and found this question:

[How to implement OnFragmentInteractionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777985/how-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener)

I've did what the guy who answered the question but the error is still there. I'm looking now about hours to find a soulution but can't find anything. Hope you can figure out what I did wrong. Thanks for helping me!
Here I call the fragment when a user clicks the settings tab in my drawer:

```js
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_startpage) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_eating) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_train) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_recipe) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
        SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
        FragmentManager settingsManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        settingsManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_navigation_drawer,
                settingsFragment,
                settingsFragment.getTag())
                .commit();
    }
```

This is my acitivity:

```js
package de.myfirstapp.myfirstapp.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Intent intentMain = getIntent();
        String dpdisplayName = intentMain.getStringExtra("displayName");
        String dploginEmail = intentMain.getStringExtra("loginEmail");

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        TextView navdisplayName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.displayName);
        navdisplayName.setText(dpdisplayName);

        TextView navloginEmail = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_email);
        navloginEmail.setText(dploginEmail);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_startpage) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_eating) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_train) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_recipe) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            FragmentManager settingsManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            settingsManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_navigation_drawer,
                    settingsFragment,
                    settingsFragment.getTag())
                    .commit();
        } //else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {

        //}

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my fragment:

```js
package de.myfitindustry.myfitindustry.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link SettingsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link SettingsFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public SettingsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment SettingsFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static SettingsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        SettingsFragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setText(R.string.hello_blank_fragment);
        return textView;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) getActivity();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at [this answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27666001). Notice the `implements Fragment_A.OnFragmentInteractionListener` part on the `Activity`. Your `Activity` needs to have something similar with your `SettingsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener`, and it'll need a similar `onFragmentInteraction()` method.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks. Now my app isn't crashing but when I click on the settings in my drawer I can't see anything but there should be a callender view :S

Comment: @MikeM. Jippi I've found it! I need to change the return statement on function onCreateView to my xml:

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);