# What's the use of Interface class in the Fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

i have a created a fragment and can't find what is the use of Interface class in this Fragment...i google it but can't find the right documentation?

Thank you for your concern!

```
public class SongListFragment extends Fragment {

        public SongListFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                songIds = getArguments().getIntArray(SONG_IDS);
            }
        }
      @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
                mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                        + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
            }
        }



//what's the use?  
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
            public void onSongSelected(int songId);
        }
}
```

Comment: you should change your topic instead of asking 
`//what's the use?` in your comment check my answer and go through the links given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***`OnFragmentInteractionListener`*** could be use to [**communicate**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) between fragments

> To allow a `Fragment` to communicate up to its Activity, you can define
>   an interface in the `Fragment` class and implement it within the
>   Activity. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during
>   its `onAttach()` lifecycle method and can then call the Interface
>   methods in order to **communicate with the Activity**.

Find another SO example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27666001/5188159)

Comment: thnx for your help!

Answer (score 2):

An interface is a reference type in Java. It is similar to class. It is a collection of abstract methods. A class implements an interface, thereby inheriting the abstract methods of the interface.

Along with abstract methods, an interface may also contain constants, default methods, static methods, and nested types. Method bodies exist only for default methods and static methods.

Writing an interface is similar to writing a class. But a class describes the attributes and behaviors of an object. And an interface contains behaviors that a class implements.

Unless the class that implements the interface is abstract, all the methods of the interface need to be defined in the class.

You might have a brief idea over [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm) Feel free to ask if any confusion rises! :)

So in your particular case your Activity must implement that `interface` `OnFragmentInteractionListener` otherwise the fragments which are attached in the `Activity`  cannot communicate with each other. Your activity should look like

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

Then in your `Activity` you implement the method `onSongSelected(int songId)`
You might get help from [here.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

@Tahmid Rahman explains what an interface is in there answer.

In this specific case the interface should be implemented in the Activity that your fragment is attaching to. That will allow the fragment to call `onSongSelected()` on the activity. Then the activity can in turn properly handle the users requested action.

Without the interface, there would not be a well defined way for the fragment to tell its parent activity that the user had clicked on a song.

Answer (score 0):

Interface is used to communicate between `fragment` and `activity` or between multiple `fragments` when an event occurs.

See the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

in your case:

```
    public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements SongListFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{
    ...

    public void onSongSelected(int songId) {  //this method must be implemented
        // The user selected the song from the list in SongListFragment
        // Do something here to display that song..in your activity
    }
}
```

you can implement the interface in your activity and write the `onSongSelected` method with the song id passed as parameter.

So basically it is used to pass selected song list information to other `activity` or `fragment` when a selection occurs