# replacing a fragment in navigation drawer keeps crashing app

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am a begginer in android studio. I'm just trying to open a fragment when I select an item from the navigation drawer menu, but the app keeps crashing.

this is my navigation drawer activity:

```
package georgia.languagelandscape2;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    SupportMapFragment sMapFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sMapFragment=SupportMapFragment.newInstance();


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainFragment()).commit();

        sMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager sFm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new ImportFragment()).commit();
        sFm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map, sMapFragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager sFm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(sMapFragment.isAdded())
            sFm.beginTransaction().hide(sMapFragment).commit();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
            if(!sMapFragment.isAdded())
                sFm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map, sMapFragment).commit();
            else
                sFm.beginTransaction().show(sMapFragment).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

           // ProfileFragment proFrag= new ProfileFragment();
          //  sFm.beginTransaction().show(proFrag).commit()

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            ProfileFragment myFragment = new ProfileFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.map, myFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        //markers, locations, everything, here
    }
}
```

and my navigation drawer content xml file
`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
```

`

Pleeeease help me I am desperate

Crashing log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: georgia.a50000incercare, PID: 4165
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: georgia.a50000incercare.NavigationDrawerActivity@9684766 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                                                                           at georgia.a50000incercare.ProfileFragment.onAttach(ProfileFragment.java:83)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1998)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:709)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: post the crash log..

Comment: try the below answer it will work...

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggest you should implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener` in your Activity

```
public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompactActivity implements 
          NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,OnMapReadyCallback
         ,ProfileFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{ //this need to be implemented
```

Also override the method in your activity

```
 @Override 
  public void onFragmentInteraction(int data){  //method that need to be implemented
   //your implementation
  }
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777985/how-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener)  Also