# How to get the same instance of activity in fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Consider the situation:
There is `mainActivity`. Form this activity we can call two fragments: `fragmentA` and `fragmentB`.

`mainActivity` has one getter `getValue` and one setter `setValue`.

Most of the time this is how application works: `mainActivity` is created. From it `fragmentA` is created. After back button is pressed in `fragmentA`, application moves back to `mainActivity` and goes to `fragmentB`.

What I want to do is, I want to `setValue` to `mainActivity` in `fragmentA` and get that value in `fragmentB`.

I am not able to do this since it looks like both fragments do not have the same instance of activity.

This is how I try to access setters/getters of `mainActivity` from `fragmentA` and `fragmentB`: `((MainActivity)getContext()).getValue();`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please post your code here of MainActivity and fragments.

Comment: Sounds like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777985/how-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener

Comment: @marius what is getValue you are passing to second fragment?

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti it is int, other value is BigDecimal (I have more than one)

Comment: @Marius You should [edit] your question to show your actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a Bunde object in Activity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
```

insert values in bundle (can pass multiple values)
key can be any String and should be unique to each value

```
 bundle.setString(key,"value");
```

create object of the corresponding Fragment and attach the bundle to it

```
 fragmentobject.setArguments(bundle);
```

in the receiving Fragment create Bundle Object

```
Bundle fragmentbundle = getArguments();
String value = fragmentbundle.getString(key);
```

this is how you pass value between fragments and activities or activities and activities

Comment: Sure, this might be the most "correct" way of doing it. However, I also need to pass BigDecimal value and as much as I know, you can't (or you need to convert it to String).

Comment: `String value = "1,000,000,000.999999999999999";
BigDecimal money = new BigDecimal(value.replaceAll(",", ""));
System.out.println(money);`

Comment: @Marius `BigDecimal` is `Serializable`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the following method:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).getValue;
```

Also, make sure that the `getValue()` method in the `MainActivity` is set to public.

I hope this helped.

Comment: As much as I know - you should use getActivity for UI related work, getContext for knowing certain states of application.

Comment: Well, I use the method I mentioned for sending and receiving data to and from my main activity. Correct me if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Coupling your Fragment to any one Activity is a poor design

Comment: @cricket_007 Could you elaborate your point, please? I don't get what you mean by coupling.

Comment: A Fragment should never know which specifiic Fragment they are attached to. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)

Comment: "You should design each fragment as a modular and reusable activity component" -- Meaning, you should be able to re-use your Fragments in *any activity*... What you have isn't wrong, but there are different ways to do it, that is all