# Using a single button going through multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an app in which I have an on boarding. I have a "next" button at the bottom of the layout which will load the next fragment. The problem is how to do this when I will have to go through 8 fragments. The order in which the fragments will be displayed, never changes. Should I use a counter or should I ask which fragment is being displayed and then go to the next? Any help is welcomed, thanks.

Comment: You can use a `ViewPager` scroll to next page on click of next.

Comment: You could define an interface in each Fragment, as explained here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777985/how-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener call some method like `onNextPage`, in which you replace the next Fragment

Comment: You can store all the 8 fragments in an array. When you push the next button, the fragment container will be replaced with the targeted next fragment from the array.

Comment: @cricket_007 wouldn´t that mean I will have to implement 8 different interfaces in my activity? one for each fragment

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: @cricket_007 decided to just Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame) on my container activity onclick and then just go through a series of if statements if(current.equals(getString(R.string.my_frag_title)){//go to next frag} thought that would be simpler and also better then loading them all at once

Comment: I never did suggest loading them all at once. A ViewPager also only would load a max of 3 at once

Comment: @cricket_007 finally  I declared a tag for each fragment in my string res and then used a switch to verify.  I did this because my frag titled will be subject to change with localization and switch needs constant values to make the match.