# control setEnabled of button in activity by clicking button in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

[image]

Hi

I'am making an app which has a 1 main activity and 3 fragments.

In activity, there is a Fragment to show another fragments

And it changes by clicking button in main activity.

There is a fragment that has a button.

I want when Button in fragment is pressed, buttons in activity will be disabled.

[How to Enable/ Disable button from another fragment in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391856/how-to-enable-disable-button-from-another-fragment-in-android)

There is an similar question and answer, so i have tried this.

UpdateButtonListener.java

```
public interface UpdateButtonListener {
    void onUpdate(boolean status);
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UpdateButtonListener{
public static UpdateButtonListener updateButton;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
updateButton = this;
}

 @Override
    public void onUpdate(boolean status) {
        mBtn1.setEnabled(false);
        mBtn3.setEnabled(false);

    }
}
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_oper, container, false);

fBtn1 = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.fBtn1);
//fbtn1 = mStopBtn      
mStopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View myView) {
                MainActivity.updateButton.onUpdate(false);
            }
        });

}
```

And when i run the app, there is an error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.samplecode4_3demo.FragmentMain.onUpdate(MainActivity.java:379)
        at com.example.samplecode4_3demo.FragmentOper$2.onClick(Fragment1.java:124)

I thnk this is because i tried to change button in activity.

How can i solve this porblem?

Answer (score 0):

are you already try yourbutton.setvisible(false)?

Comment: I used button.setVisibility(Vew.INVISIBLE);
and It has an error
Not allowed to start service Intent {}: app is in background uid UidRecord{cee171a u0a404 TPSL idle change:idle|cached procs:1 proclist:18123, seq(0,0,0)}

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

You have not initialized your variables. `mBtn1` and `mBtn3` are null as they have not been set correctly.

**The Quick Solution**

Initialize your variables:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UpdateButtonListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        updateButton = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.this_activity_layout); // Set layout with views
        mBtn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1); // Find Button 1
        mBtn3 = findViewById(R.id.btn3); // Find Button 3
    }
}
```

**The Complete Solution**

After doing the above, please read: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating on how to properly communicate with activity via fragment. Then:

1. Remove `public static UpdateButtonListener updateButton;` (you should not have a static reference to a button).
2. Update fragment button click as so:

   ```
   mStopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View myView) {
           // MainActivity.updateButton.onUpdate(false); // Don't access STATIC reference like this

           // Instead get the activity INSTANCE and invoke method on it
           UpdateButtonListener listener = (UpdateButtonListener) getActivity();
           if (listener != null) {
               listener.onUpdate(false);
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Hope that helps!