# How to Manage Button from another fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragment

i use a multiple fragments
one of fragment contains 2 Buttons one of them `setenabled(False)`
how can i make `setenabled(True)` from another fragment ? is it possible?

Comment: There is an answer from a topic on stackoverflow if you watn to take a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391856/how-to-enable-disable-button-from-another-fragment-in-android

Comment: it doesnt work idk why every think was right but no changes happen , any suggestion pls? thank you .

Answer (score 0):

you can use callBack to achieve this when you do something in your other fragments then callBack will listen to your first fragment and then you can enable and disable your view.

Another Simple way use sharepreference and when you perform some action in your other fragments update your sharepreference and then simply get that shareference data in your first fragments and udpate your views accordingly.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

editor.putBoolean("key", true);
editor.apply();

then get your shareprefence in your first fragment and hide your view

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

boolean name = prefs.getBoolean("key", false);

if(name)
{
hide your views in this block
}

Comment: thank you but both ways i dont know how to do them , sharedpreference i used it just to save strings not other thing , any link may help?

Comment: kinldy check my updated answer. use sharepreference and save boolean. Access sharepreference in your first fragment if it is true then hide your view if it is false then show your view.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using shared preferences.
Suppose you have FragmentA with buttons and FragmentB.
in order to enable buttons in FragmentA from FragmentB I would create a Custom listener which has a function called setEnabled (When it is called it would enablwe the button in FragmentA) in fragmentA, We want to pass this listener to FragmentB.
When and event occurs in FragmentB which you want it to trigger the setEnable for FragmentA I would call listener.setEnable which will enable the button in fragmentA in FragmentB