# Getting EditText Value from a Fragment in main Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have placed three edit text in a fragment and want to get the values of the edit text in the fragment from the main activity. I tried the following code but its throwing ***nullpointerexception*** in **getName()** method.

**Fragment Class**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

EditText name, age, gender;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container);

    name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    age = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.age);
    gender = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.gender);

    return view;
}

public String getName(){
    String name1 = name.getText().toString().trim();
    return name1;
}
public String getAge(){
    String age1 = age.getText().toString().trim();
    return age1;
}
public String getGender(){
    String gender1 = gender.getText().toString().trim();
    return gender1;
}
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Fragment1 f1;
Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    f1 = new Fragment1();

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, f1.getName() +" "+ f1.getAge() +" "+ f1.getGender(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Edit:**

**activity_main.xml**

this is my main activity ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ganesh.fragtask.MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.ganesh.fragtask.Fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat**
this is the exception i get when i click the button

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.ganesh.fragtask, PID: 6015
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.example.ganesh.fragtask.Fragment1.getName(Fragment1.java:33)
                                                                           at com.example.ganesh.fragtask.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:25)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5611)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22276)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6195)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
```

Comment: You should make the Fragment talk to the Activity, not call Fragment methods directly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777985/how-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. For those who are getting error for this `Fragment_Example f1 = (Fragment_Example)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);`. Use this `Fragment_Example f1 = (Fragment_Example)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f1 = new Fragment()
```

This is not how you add fragments. You are just creating a new fragment instance here. The fragment's onCreateView never gets called because the fragment has not been added. Due to this, the editText variable is null and you get the exception. Please study fragments a little bit.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

This is how you add a fragment :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frag_layout_id, f1, "fragment_identifier").commit();
```

**EDIT**

Since the question has been edited with the xml, although you have declared the fragment in XML, the f1 instance in your java does not refer to that. To get a handle for the instance added through xml, use this

```
Fragment_Example f1 = (Fragment_Example)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is  `f1 = new Fragment1();` you have just created a object for `fragment` class, but this is not the exact way to call the `fragment`. You are supposed to set `transition` using the `fragmentManager`. If you didn't set in this way, then the `frgament Lifecycle` method's won't be called. So, in your scenario `onCreateView()` won't be called and the views are not initialized(As your stackTrace clearly states the view is not initialized). Try the below code

```
f1 = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, f1, 
f1 .getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

I hope you are aware of the other fragment container.i.e., having a `FrameLayout` in `MainActivity` and adding the `Fragment` to that container.

Hope this is helpful:)

Comment: Sorry didn't get you. what do you mean by other fragment container.

Comment: @ganeshvicky: We need to put fragment container in mainactivity.. here in the above example the id of the container is R.id.fragment_frame...

Answer (score 0):

I think you name, age, and gender views are not initialized:
try changing your **onCreateView()** like this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container);
    name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.your_id);
    age = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.your_id);
    gender = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.your_id);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry i initialized the views but forgot to add it in the question. I have edited it once again but it still doesnt work.