# "Modifier static not allowed" when trying to connect fragment to activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Learning how to use fragments in android. 
I'm following documentation on Android:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

According to documentation I'm suppose to use static to implement my fragment interface in my activity.

However I'm getting error. "modifier static not allowed"

My host activity:

```
public static class RecordWorkoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements WorkoutFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{
```

My fragment:

```
public class WorkoutFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
```

Ultimately I need my activity to display one fragment if on landscape orientation and a different fragment if on Portrait but for know I just need to be able to connect my fragments with my Activity.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation most probably includes `static` in `public static class` because the classes in examples there are inner classes.

If you implement your activity not as an inner class, you don't need the `static` modifier. Just remove it.

Comment: I doubt it, they have `MainActivity` class as static, which is wrong in all possible ways. Probably just a typo.

Comment: If I remove static I get. "Class must be declared abstract or implement abstract method OnFragmentIteraction

Comment: @user2300867 Well, you do need to actually implement the method.

Comment: Makes sense. I was just trying to stick with the documentation. Thanks. Also this was very helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777985/how-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why that's part of the documentation, because as explained in [this article](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-static-class-tutorial.html), static classes can only exist nested in other classes. Have you tried removing "static" and running the code?

Comment: If I remove static I get. "Class must be declared abstract or implement abstract method OnFragmentIteraction"

Comment: That's because the compiler is now processing more of your code. Have you actually implemented the method(s) contained in `OnFragmentInteractionListener`?

Comment: Got it. Thanks!