# Android: Error: must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Tags: android

I am getting runtime error :  `must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener`

This is my fragment class file which renders two tabs, tab1 and tab2:

```
package com.ercess.ercess_app;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class MyEventsFragment extends Fragment implements Tab1.OnFragmentInteractionListener,Tab2.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myevents, container, false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        //tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

This is the java code for tab1 which I want to render from the fragment:

```
package com.ercess.ercess_app;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class MyEventsFragment extends Fragment implements Tab1.OnFragmentInteractionListener,Tab2.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myevents, container, false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        //tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

This is my logcat:

```
09-11 18:05:15.231 6765-6765/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10060: Read-only file system
09-11 18:09:40.144 6765-6765/com.ercess.ercess_app **E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ercess.ercess_app, PID: 6765
    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ercess.ercess_app.Welcome@3c6aa0fb must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
        at com.ercess.ercess_app.Tab1.onAttach(Tab1.java:83)**
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1404)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1195)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1078)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:117)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2408)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:168)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootIm
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26473328/3395198

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem, then i figured what was wrong.
I forgot to uncheck include fragment fancy methods and and include interface callbacks while creating one of the tabs.
You might have done the same

Answer (score 0):

When implements an interface, you must override the function defined in the interface, so check the `Tab1` class file to find the function signature and override it in your `MyEventsFragment` file

Or you could press `alt + enter` when cursor in  `Tab1.OnFragmentInteractionListener,Tab2.OnFragmentInteractionListener`, IDE(android studio )will prompt for you how to do.

Comment: That's what I did as explained by Bla.. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777985/how-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to make your calling activity implement these interfaces. Right now EventsFragment is a... fragment. Fragments should not communicate directly.

> All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done either through a shared
>   ViewModel or through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should
>   never communicate directly.

More info: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating