# App crash when load a fragment on startup

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm currently learning android, and in my current project I'm using fragment to load the start page.

Here is my FrameLayout:

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" /><![CDATA[
/>
```

I use a void in my activity to load the fragment, and here is the code:

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    // load fragment
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

and on oncreate activity, I use this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_activity);

    toolbar = getSupportActionBar();
    toolbar.setTitle("Home");
    loadFragment(new HomeFragment());

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}
```

but it seems my app always crashes on startup. Any ideas?

btw sorry for bad english!

Edit: 
The problem seems on the code transaction.replace()

```
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
```

when I commented it out, my app works, but I can't load a fragment then

Edit 2:
here is the cause of my app's crash:

> 2018-11-07 08:44:44.469 20414-20414/com.example.han.xvit
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 2018-11-07 08:44:44.470
>   20414-20414/com.example.han.xvit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: com.example.han.xvit, PID: 20414
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.han.xvit/com.example.han.xvit.home_activity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.han.xvit.home_activity@a800718
>   must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2782)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1521)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.han.xvit.home_activity@a800718 must implement
>   OnFragmentInteractionListener
>           at com.example.han.xvit.HomeFragment.onAttach(HomeFragment.java:83)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1404)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1195)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1078)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:117)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2408)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1249)
>           at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6897)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2782) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1521) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)

Edit 3:
I successfully solved the problem. It seems I am lacking several fragment implementations on my home activity

The solution can be seen at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777985/how-to-implement-onfragmentinteractionlistener)

Comment: Maybe remove `<![CDATA` and `/>` from your XML layout?

Comment: Noope, still crashes

Comment: I see, you don't need those anyway. Could you please post the error log too?

Comment: what is 
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" /><![CDATA[  used for? are you meant to be passing in a string there?

Edit: You appear to be trying to add a "Appbar scrolling view behaviour" to a framelayout, i don't believe you require that line of code there, what is it you're trying to achieve with this line? (i might be able to give a better solution to what you want to do)

Comment: The problem is, since i compile the app on my phone, there is no error log. The app just crashes, thats it.

Comment: I myself don't know what " app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" /><![CDATA[" is used for. It is automatically generated by android studio.

Comment: `com.example.han.xvit.home_activity@a800718 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener`

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `<![CDATA[/>` so the layout becomes like this:

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Then, from the following error log:

> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.han.xvit.home_activity@a800718 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener at com.example.han.xvit.HomeFragment.onAttach(HomeFragment.java:83) at

it means that you need to implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener` in your Activity because your `HomeFragment` needs it. Please check your HomeFragment `onAttach`.